# pandas sum of column based on index

Tags: python, pandas

How to sum pandas columns based on index choice

```
        'A'   'B'
```

---

```
'G9'    15   16
```

---

```
'G10'   20   30
```

---

```
'G9PRO'  1   11
```

if I choose 'G9' I want to get this dataFrame

```
        'logs'
```

---

```
'A'     15
```

---

```
'B'     16
```

and if I choose 'G9' and 'G10' I want to get this dataFrame

```
        'logs'
```

---

```
'A'     35
```

---

```
'B'     46
```

and so on, I tried the sum function but it did not give the right result

Answer (score 2):

You can use `df.index.isin()` and `.sum()` to generate the results you need

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'A': [15, 20, 1],
    'B': [16, 30, 11]
}, index=['G9', 'G10', 'G9PRO'])
df
```

Test Case #1

```
selected = ['G9', 'G10']
sum_df = df[df.index.isin(selected)].sum()

A    35
B    46
dtype: int64
```

Test Case #2

```
selected = ['G9']
sum_df = df[df.index.isin(selected)].sum()

A    15
B    16
dtype: int64
```